# Will macbook pro mid 2012 gt650m show 2560 resolution on a 4k display?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display, display

I have a mid 2012 macbook pro with a GT650M graphics card. From my research I have found that the maximum resolution for this card is 2560 x 1440. I currently run a thunderbolt external display with it.

I am thinking about purchasing a 4k monitor. I have a windows 8.1 machine with a GTX 650 TI Boost that I am positive will run the 4k display. So my question is this...

If i plug the 4k display into the imac will I AT LEAST get the 2560 x 1440 resolution of my thunderbolt display on the 4k?

I understand that i will NOT get true 4k when using the macbook, but i'm hoping to get 2560 resolution when the macbook is plugged in and 4k resolution when the PC is plugged in.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

No it will not. According to http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6008:

"You can use 4K displays and Ultra HD TVs with these Mac computers.

MacBook Pro (Retina, Late 2013 and later)
Mac Pro (Late 2013)
iMac (27-inch, Late 2013 and later)
Mac mini (Late 2014)"